# How to find level of seniority an employee level0, level1..........leveln manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the level0, level1, level2 .....levelN manager for my company. How to do that.

```
CREATE TABLE Emp_demo (
        emp_ID INT,
        emp_Name NVARCHAR (50),
        emp_sal_K INT,
        emp_manager INT) 
    GO

    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (1,'Ali', 200,2)
    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770,4)
    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140,2)
    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (4,'LILY', 770,Null)
    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (5,'John', 1240,6)
    INSERT INTO Emp_demo VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140,4)
```

For e.g here 4 is CEO because he reports to no one. Level0 employees are 1,3,5 because no one reports to them. After that  come employees 2 and 6 who have 4 as their reporting manager and last is 4 who is CEO because he reports to no one.

How to basically find the level of seniority of a person.

Level 0: lowest level employee
level 1: First level employee
......
level n : CEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [`recursive CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions):

```
with cte as (
  select emp_id, emp_name, 0 level, emp_manager
  from emp_demo
  union all
  select c.emp_id, c.emp_name, c.level + 1, e.emp_manager
  from emp_demo e inner join cte c
  on c.emp_manager = e.emp_id
  where c.emp_manager is not null
)
select emp_id, emp_name, 
  max(max(level)) over () - max(level) level
from cte
group by emp_id, emp_name
order by emp_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77cadfd84226fc157ab2cac55f901b0e).
Results:

```
> emp_id | emp_name | level
> -----: | :------- | ----:
>      1 | Ali      |     0
>      2 | Zaid     |     1
>      3 | Mohd     |     0
>      4 | LILY     |     2
>      5 | John     |     0
>      6 | Mike     |     1
```

Comment: I have understood everything except for this `max(max(level)) over () - max(level) level`. What does this mean? I have never seen over() being used alone. I have only seen it with partition or with order by etc. Pls explain.. Then ill accept answer

Comment: The recursive cte returns all possible levels for each emp_id but in reverse order meaning it returns 0 for LILLY, 2 for John etc. you can check it by using `select * from cte` instead of the last `select...`. So it is not enough just to get the maximum level of each emp_id. I must subtract that max level of each emp_id from the max level of all emp_ids. This is what `max(max())...` does. `max() over ()` is a window function. A good source about window functions is this: https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @Count int = 0,@InitCount int = 0

select emp_manager from Emp_demo group by emp_manager

set @Count = @@ROWCOUNT - 2;

declare @Emp_Table table(emp_ID INT,Level Int)

insert into @Emp_Table (emp_ID,Level) select emp_ID,0 from Emp_demo where emp_ID not in (select emp_manager from Emp_demo where emp_manager is not null)

while @InitCount < @Count
begin
insert into @Emp_Table (emp_ID,Level)
select emp_manager,@InitCount+1 from Emp_demo where emp_ID in (select emp_ID from @Emp_Table where [Level] = @InitCount) group by emp_manager
set @InitCount = @InitCount + 1;
end;

select * from @Emp_Table --Result with Id and level
```